# Solving coupled real and complex PDE with NDSolve, real solution giving complex results

Tags: differential-equations

I'm working with a set of coupled nonlinear PDE with regards to lasers. This is a major part of my dissertation so I don't want to go far into those details.

The main issue is this: The equations dictate the spatial dependence of electron-hole distributions in lasers by relating the field equations to the complex permittivity. The part of the permittivity which relates the e-h pairs is real, the field is of course complex. When I try to solve the system of equations the permittivity equations comes out complex. This can wildly effect the dynamics of the field equation because the system will not reach saturation.

I've gone over the derivations over and over again so you will have to take my word for it when I say the equations to be solved are correct. It is my understanding assumptions can't be used inside NDSolve, or at least not in any obvious way.

The code used is below, and the constants defined are below it

```
solum = 
  NDSolveValue[
    {2/(w0*t1)*D[ufield[x, t], {t, 1}] - I*D[ufield[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
      (eodub - (1 + I*χ1) ϕ[x, t])/er*ufield[x, t] == 0,
     ufield[0, t] == u0*100, 
     ufield[100*l*wavek, t] == u0*100, 
     ufield[x, 0] == u0*100,
     D[ϕ[x, t], {t, 1}] + ϕ[x, t] - 2*finalpump[x] + 
       δ^2*Re[ufield[x, t]*Conjugate[ufield[x, t]]]*ϕ[x, t] == 0,
     ϕ[x, 0] == 0},
    {ufield, ϕ},
    {x, 0, 100*l*wavek},
    {t, 0, 0.5},
   MaxSteps -> 10^7,
   MaxStepFraction -> {1/300, 1/30}, 
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
   InterpolationOrder -> All]

w0=2*Pi*3.43*10^14
t1=10^-8
er=12.9
e0dub=2.24006*10^-6
l=0.6*10^-4
wavek=258195
χ1=5.838*10^11
δ=0.00333909
```

finalpump is the spatial pump distribution which can be multiplied by any factor to change the total pump intensity. This was obtained by curve fitting from data obtained from a charged particle transport code. The curve has the form

```
finalpump[x_]=qq*gauss[x, sig, 0.0051]*Sech[pp*x]
gauss[x_, σ_, μ_]=σ*Sqrt[2*Pi])^-1*Exp[-0.5*(x - μ)^2/σ^2];
```

The fitting coefficients are:

```
{qq,sig,pp}={29.9766, 0.000850133, -6363.25}
```

`u0` is a small number, it can be 1 for all that it matters. As long as it's not zero.

Ideally, the permittivity and E*E of the field should basically follow the shape of the pump (the field of course E=0 at x=0 due to the BC).

So when I try to run the above, phi becomes complex. Considering the permittivity given in the literature is of the form

$\qquad eps=er+de(x)+i(e0''-e''(x))$

Where $e''(x)$ is the phi in my equations of interest (I'm using e instead of epsilon becomes I'm not familiar with the macros here). It makes no sense for $e''(x)$ to also be complex. By examining the phi equation it becomes clear that phi should never become complex since the field is given by E*E. If you notice from my code, I even wrapped E*E inside the `Re[]` command hoping it would cut off any small imaginary factors.

I've tried solving a rederived version where I split the single complex field equation into two real functions representing the real and imaginary parts of the field. That program has been running for over 3 hours and I have no idea when it'll finish or if the results will even be useful/correct.

Here are plots of the results from the code given above. Notice that when the permittivity solution becomes complex the field equation goes nuts. The permittivity plot is `Re[phi]` and the field is `E*E`. I would also give the plot of `Im[phi]` if Mathematica weren't currently running.

[image: permittivity results]
[image: field results]

In the end, I want to know if there's a way to keep phi real without distorting the "true" results.

Comment: I have new results but the site keeps telling me I have code improperly formatted, even if the only thing I add are the new images.

The coupled real equations returned with an error after about 4 hours. I reran the above code with two different modifications

I changed

    ufield[x,t]*Conjugate[ufield[x,t]]

with

    Re[ufield[x,t]]^2+Im[ufield[x,t]]^2

and

    Norm[ufield[x,t]]^2

The new code runs much faster, but the end results are the same. I'd post the new figures but I can't even edit my original post.

Comment: `u0` is undefined, as is `eodub`.  The latter probably should be `e0dub`.  Fix these, and I shall see what I can do.  In any case, good luck on your dissertation.  By the way, I have never encountered "code improperly formatted" from StackExchange.  If the problem persists, consider asking about it in Meta Mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.